# VLC not minimizing or maximizing properly

Tags: vlc-media-player, media-player

I have got ThinkPad 13 with mint 18.  When I try to minimize the VLC window the main part stays on its place, only the control panels will minimize.  I can even click on the part that stayed and it won't recognize it and click on stuff that is behind the window like nothing is there.
When I try to maximize a video, the main window will again stay the same, only black background will appear around it.
The same is happening with GNOME MPlayer, only when I maximize it, the background is blue.

Can anyone help me? 
Thank you very much

Comment: have you got any screenshots on this?

Comment: I have tried, but when I screenshot the minimize bug, the VLC window is not on screenshot but it I can see it there. Similar with maximize - screenshot is all blue but I see the window and blue background. Got photos - do you want them?

Comment: If you can upload them that would be great

Comment: is it the same video everytime or have you tried different?

Comment: Yes, multiple videos